# How to find out from the logs what caused my program shutdown?

Tags: logs, daemon

I am launching a program via -ssh in daemon mode. After couple days my program is down. Usually on other servers that's not happening. How I would figure out that?

Comment: You wrote that program, so shouldn't you know best what it logs or doesn't log? I am confused.

Comment: I checked `cat /var/log/syslog | grep myprogram -i` there are is nothing

Comment: No info about shutting down in debug.log of my program as well